# Giving a DIV a maximize button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a div on my page that I would like a user to be able to click and maximize the div so it appears over the whole screen. I would like it to be similar to how Gmail has a button that allows you to maximize what the user is looking at, and then return to the original size with another click of a button.

The problem I ran into is that my div contains 3 divs inside of it. 
Here is my HTML

```
    <div id="pre">
       <div id="pre-title">Pre Reading</div>
       <div id="pre-text">blahhh.</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="passage">
        <div id="passage-title">2.2.3</div>
        <div id="passage-text">blahlkdsfjahlskdjfh</div>
    </div>
    <div id="media">
        <div id="media-title">Media Videos</div>
        <div id="media-text">even more garbage</div>
    </div>
```

These div's are placed directly next to each other on the page and I would like it if I could include a button next to the title that would allow the user to make the section larger, like they were maximizing the readings.

Comment: Please add your JavaScript/JQuery of what you did so for, also it's not clear what you want else than maximizing and minimizing div. What is 'title that would allow....'?

Answer (score 1):

Just giving you the glimpse, change styling as per your requirement.

[WORKING:DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j4sgg0L8/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".readmore").click(function () {
        var readMore = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        var mainDiv = $("#" + readMore).parent().attr("id");
        var textDiv = mainDiv +"-text";
        $("."+ textDiv).toggleClass("maximize");
    });

    $(".close").click(function () {
     $(".pre-text, .passage-text, .media-text").removeClass("maximize");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for, but for some reason I get two errors.  1) the close button only appears for pre-reading in your demo, and none of my divs.  2) when I put it on my page, it appears to just gray everything behind it out, but I can still see some things behind it.  Is it possible so it appears as a pop-out box in front of everything else?

Comment: See now here http://jsfiddle.net/j4sgg0L8/1/ And i would suggest you to first learn basics first.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pre').click(function(e) {
    $('#pre').toggleClass('maximized', 500); // 500 ms to animate 
  } );
} );
</script>

<style>
  #pre {
    width: 50px;
  }
  #pre.maximized {
   width: 500px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi Maskim, please consider including an explanation of the change.